# Как изменить размер шрифта в JPopupMenu

Tags: java, swing

Я добавил размер шрифта но он не изменился.

```
btnUser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            int x = btnUser.getX();
            int y = btnUser.getY() + btnUser.getHeight();
            JPopupMenu jPopupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
            jPopupMenu.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));

            jPopupMenu.add(new AbstractAction("Exit") {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);                     
                }
            });
            jPopupMenu.show(panel, x, y);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я помню, **popupMenu** состоит из **menuItem** и уже у них можно задавать **font**. Попробуйте нечто подобное:

```
//...
JPopupMenu jPopupMenu = new JPopupMenu();

JMenuItem item;

popup.add(item = new JMenuItem("Первый"));
item.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
popup.add(item = new JMenuItem("Второй"));
item.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15));
//...
```

Comment: Да то что нужно спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал вот так.

```
JMenuItem mntmExit = new JMenuItem("EXIT");
mntmExit.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
mntmExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
jPopupMenu.add(mntmExit);
```